# Angular : Updating model doesnt work on consecutive click events

Tags: angular

so i have a div which iterates and populate a table, using *ngFor attribute. And on the loop i am using the data value of it to assign the background color of my div. something like this as follows :

```
<div class="col-xs-1-10" *ngFor="let item of combinations">
<div [style.background-color]="item.colorCode" [style.pointerEvents]="(item.slotStatus == 'CLOSED') ? 'none' : 'auto'" (click)="selectItem(item)">
  <span>{{item.slotStatus}}</span>
</div>
```

I can validate that initial load is working fine, Also the 1st click event on the selected item is indeed changing the DIV background color + it also was abl to update the item parameter as expected. But on next clicks it not working background color is not changed and item parameter was not updated. Please see my code for selectItem method :

```
selectItem(item: any) {

console.log(item);

if (item.colorCode = '#CA3433') {
  item.colorCode = '#3342FF';
}
else if (item.colorCode = '#3342FF') {
  item.colorCode = '#CA3433';
}

console.log(item);
```

}

Im a nutshell what i need is 
1. Select/De-select item and update a list (maybe build a session storage from it)
2. Changed the color coding of the div as indicator to the user wheter the item was select/unselect

Comment: Comparison is done using `==` or `===`, single `=` is used to assign value to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update  `selectItem` to this ( = is assassin operator and == or === is equal operator)

```
selectItem(item: any) {

console.log(item);

if (item.colorCode == '#CA3433') {
  item.colorCode = '#3342FF';
}
else if (item.colorCode == '#3342FF') {
  item.colorCode = '#CA3433';
}

console.log(item);
}
```

Check this like for more information about comparison [**Comparison Operators**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

[javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)

Comment: @Oen44 .. I so want to edit the answer, but then other won't get the context of your epic comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single `=` in if statements, that's not how you compare values.

#### Fixed code

```
if (item.colorCode == '#CA3433') {
  item.colorCode = '#3342FF';
}
else if (item.colorCode == '#3342FF') {
  item.colorCode = '#CA3433';
}
```

If you want to compare values without worrying about their types, use `==`, if you want to make sure that both values are the same type, use `===`.

#### Example

```
('123' == 123) // returns true
('123' === 123) // returns false
('123' === '123') // returns true
```